# How to assign string to integer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Here is the code now:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var j,r:integer; k:string;
begin
  k := Edit1.Text;

  if StrToInt(k) > 0 then 
    if StrToInt(k)<10 then
      r := StrToInt(k);
  if StrToInt(k) = 10 then
    r := 1;
  if StrToInt(k) > 10 then 
    if StrToInt(k) < 190 then
      j:=StrToInt(k) mod 10;
  r := j-1;

  ShowMessage('Na toj poziciji se nalazi: '+ IntToStr(r));
end;
```

When I write `k:=Edit1.Text` option is not even suggested to use. Anybody got a solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To assign text from `TEdit` instance to your `Integer` variable, you can use `StrToInt` function and specify `Edit`.Text` as its argument.

Comment: @Edin You edit has been reverted because you cannot ask new questions by editing existing questions. If you have a new question, please ask a new question. However, please don't view this site as a means to get others to do your work for you. If you are stuck on beginner mistakes, spend at least some time researching how to fix them. At the very least read the error messages and warnings and try to think what they mean.

Comment: it was disuscussion about the same program lol

Comment: Yes I know. But here on SO we ask one question at a time. Once you have an answer, the question is over. It's fine to edit the question to improve or clarify the original question, but not to ask new questions. I believe this is covered by the topics at the [help].

Comment: FWIW, calling `StrToInt(k)` everywhere is not really a good idea. The conversion from string to integer takes time and doing it again and again will slow down your program (ok, not this trivial code, but it could become important in a larger project). Rather do `myInt := StrToInt(k);` once and then use that integer instead.

Comment: At least use `StrToIntDef` to avoid exceptions while user is deciding what to type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to set 'k', which is declared an integer, to a string from Edit1.Text

Convert Edit1.Text to an integer using StrToInt and try it again. BTW the message: "Incompatabile types: 'Integer' and 'TCaption'" means exactly that. It's incompatible.

Comment: I apologize I'm new at the forum/site, but I'm having problems with sendning comments. Is there any way where I can do everything same as making a post?

Comment: @EdinHajdarevic, if you want add something important, you can edit your own question. Just click `edit` button below your question and add information.

Comment: checkout the post now